# How to list indices of list elements that meet a condition?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a tidy way to create a list of the indices of elements of a list that meet specified conditions?

This method gets the job done, but it's clumsy and not conducive to nesting:

```
x = RandomReal[1, 100];
t = {};
Do[If[x[[i]] < .2, t = Join[t, {i}]], {i, Length[x]}];
t
```

(* {13, 24, 31, 32, 44, 45, 46, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 57, 65, 70, 75, 76, 81, 87, 97} *)

Position almost does what I want, but it annoyingly returns a list of lists instead of a list of indices:

```
Position[x, _?(# < .2 &)]
```

(* {{5}, {14}, {16}, {19}, {22}, {24}, {28}, {42}, {43}, {45}, {50}, \
{51}, {54}, {58}, {63}, {72}, {86}, {91}, {98}}   *)

This prevents me from being able to use the output of Position as a list of indices.  So this fails:

```
x = RandomReal[1,100];
y = RandomReal[1,Length[x]];
tt = Position[x, _?(# < .2 &)];
y[[tt]]
```

I am also kind of curious, WHY does MMa so often give results in that irritating "list of lists" format above?

Comment: Hi, take a look at `Position's` documentation page. `Position[x, _?(# < .2 &)]`.

Comment: @Kuba,  Thanks.  That almost works, but it returns a list with each index as a list:  {{5}, {14}, {16}, {19}}.  I need just a list of indices.

Comment: @JerryGuern "Position returns a list of positions in a form suitable for use in Extract, ReplacePart, and MapAt." [Docs.]

Comment: This should be considerably faster than `Position`: `SparseArray[UnitStep[x - 0.2], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]`.  More examples found within: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=SparseArray+UnitStep

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm not clear on why this was closed as off-topic.  Granted, if could have found the answer the Position documentation, IF I had known that Position was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You mentioned `Position` might be a solution and wondered about its results.  I usually read the documentation in such circumstances, which in fact is what I did.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I see the problem. I asked the question not knowing about Position, the first commenter told me about Position, but I still didn't know about Flatten so Position alone didn't solve my problem, so I edited the question to mention that.

Comment: Of course, I voted 3rd; I can't speak for the others. I think questions have to stand as written, in general. If you're interested in efficient ways, such as suggested by Mr.Wizard, you might edit the question to emphasize that and remove the last question about `Position`; then we can see if it gets enough votes to be reopened. OTOH, it might still be closed as a duplicate of one of the questions in Mr.Wizard's link. There are a lot of [list-manipulation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) questions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Position and Flatten.  Thanks for the help, Kuba.

```
tt = Flatten[Position[x, _?(# < .2 &)]]
```